# Django web app "Not allowed to load local resource /.css file"

Tags: html, css, django

I cant load css file in my web page it just gives me a simple page without css elements as shown in the screenshot and says it cant load local resource [Page and inspect elememt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPWnz.png)
I've loaded the static files in settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')

]
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
```

added url

```
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

used this in html

```
{%load static%}
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>LOGIN</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/styles/style.css' %}">
</head>
```

also did manage.py collectstatic

followed the docs dont know where i went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `link` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/styles/style.css' %}">
```

That is enough to load the file; so you don't need the following:

```
{% include "assets/styles/style.css" %}
```

---

and also, you should change your settings like below if your css file is in `BASE_DIR/assets/style.css`:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS=[

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
]
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found )gave me this now

Comment: If you have `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')]` and `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')`, with a CSS file located at `BASE_DIR/assets/style.css`, you should be able to access it with `{% include "styles/style.css" %}`.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're using `{% include "assets/styles/style.css" %}` instead of `{% include "styles/style.css" %}` (you should not include the "assets" itself).

Comment: ERRORS:
?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.
i get this when i add both static_root and staticfiles_DIRS. need to remove one and then the error goes away

Comment: i removed the {%include part% } as you recommended

Comment: You have the same name for `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT`. Change them as I mentioned in the above comment.